# Is "git push --mirror" sufficient for backing up my repository?

Tags: git, backup

I'm a solo developer, working in a local Git repository. For backups, I want to send an exact copy of that repository off to another server.

Is it sufficient to do this?

```
git push --mirror
```

I'm asking because I can sometimes run this command two or three times before Git tells me "Everything up-to-date", so apparently it's not an exact mirror. It seems to be re-pushing tracking branches...?

```
$ git push --mirror
Counting objects: 42, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
Writing objects: 100% (30/30), 5.09 KiB, done.
Total 30 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://my/repo/url
   c094a10..0eedc92  mybranch -> mybranch
$ git push --mirror
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://my/repo/url
   c094a10..0eedc92  origin/mybranch -> origin/mybranch
$ git push --mirror
Everything up-to-date
```

What is happening, and is this a good strategy?

Edit: I don't like to use something like `git bundle` or `.tar.bz2` archives, because I'd like the backup to be an accessible working copy. Since my backup server is connected to the net and always on, this is a nice way to access the repository when I'm on the road.

Comment: See also: [Backup a Local Git Repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository)

Comment: Does this backup the reflog as well?  If not then this is a pretty poor backup.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say this is a perfectly acceptable strategy for backing up your repository. It should perform a push to your origin remote for every ref in the repository. Making it a complete 'mirror' of your local repository.

EDIT: I've just seen your updated description in the question. It seems git is pushing your remote ref to the remote itself along with everything else. Once the push has finished, the remote ref will be updated to reflect that you have just pushed to it. This will now be out of date with the remote repository so a further push is necessary. If this doesn't satisfy you. You can delete this remote ref with

> git push :origin/mybranch

and then use

> git push --all

remember that this won't push any new branches you create though.

Comment: Then why does it do something when I run it a second time?

Comment: What do you mean by 'something'? Is the repository you're pushing to a bare clone? Can you provide more detail as I'm sure that git push --mirror should provide the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Also worth knowing is cloning the repository using the --mirror option then using 'git remote add --mirror <name> <url>'. This will automatically mirror so you should just be able to run 'git push'.

Comment: Note that `git remote add --mirror` now shows this error: warning: --mirror is dangerous and deprecated; please
 use --mirror=fetch or --mirror=push instead . Based on the `man` docs, it appears people wanting to treat a remote as a "backup" should use the `=push` option.

Answer (score 48):

The reason you see something pushed the second time is that `--mirror` pushes a little more than you expect. Apart from your local branches, it also pushes your remote branches, because mirror implies *everything*. So when you push normally (or with `--mirror`), `mybranch` is pushed and `origin/mybranch` is updated to reflect the new status on origin. When you push with `--mirror`, `origin/mybranch` is also pushed.

This results in the strangeness you see, and also in a worse strangeness when you pull from that remote; you would get branches named `origin/origin/mybranch` etc. So it's usually best to use `--mirror` for one time copies, and just use normal push (maybe with `--all`) for normal uses.

To always push all branches and tags, you can update `.git/config` like so:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = ...
  fetch = ...
  push = +refs/heads/*
  push = +refs/tags/*
```

That will make a normal push similar to a mirror, except that it won't delete branches that don't exist at the source or for non-fast-forward updates.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I do recall having seen these `origin/origin/*` branches at some point, but apparently I deleted them. The problem with `--all` is that it won't push any new branches, nor will it delete any deleted branches. It's not fool-proof enough, and I can be a fool at times. There's no way to tell `--mirror` to ignore remote branches?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get it to ignore remotes. You could, however, modify yout `.git/config` to push more per default. I've updated the answer.

Comment: "--mirror also pushes your remote branches". This only applies to remote branches that you've already fetched/tracked, right? For example, if you just did a `git clone`, you would only have the `master` branch, so `git push --mirror` would only mirror the `master` branch, and none of the other remote branches.

Answer (score 30):

Unfortunately, you don't get an exact copy with push.  You [lose your stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository).

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. It does not really matter, though, because the stash is supposed to be a really short-term thing anyway.

Comment: Yes, I think it's good enough for backup, but not ideal for syncing.

Besides, we all know how long we sometimes depend on supposedly short-term things. ;)

Comment: If you are keeping stashes for any amount of time, maybe you need to get more comfortable making branches (:

Answer (score 8):

What I do is:

Setup the repo: `git clone --mirror user@server:/url-to-repo.git`

Then when you want to refresh the backup: `git remote update` from the clone location.

This backs up all branches, including new branches that get added later, although it's worth noting that branches that get deleted do not get deleted from the clone (which for a backup may be a good thing).

From http://www.garron.me/en/bits/backup-git-bare-repo.html

Answer (score 4):

I usually use `git push --all`. I only use --mirror when i need to push newly created branches or I deleted some branches and dont want to name them one by one. Otherwise the `push --all` usually works as I need.

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit than [Amber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333102/is-git-push-mirror-sufficient-for-backing-up-my-repository/3333129#3333129), you could:

- push to a local backup [created with `git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251713/backup-of-github-repo/1251717#1251717)
- copy that unique file to your remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working for a long time trying to develop a bash script to safelly backup a set of repositories from a git server to another one.

I believe the following script works properly, but I recomend testing it.

Problem statement: One has a set of repositories hosted in a server called origin. One needs to periodicaly backup all repositories to another host (called upstream), taking all branches.

Solution:

```
declare -a projects=("rep1 rep2 rep3 rep4")

for project in ${projects}; do
    cd $project;
    pwd;
    git fetch --all -v;
    git status -v;
    for remote in `git branch -r | grep origin | grep -v /HEAD`; do
        echo Remote $remote; 
        git checkout --track $remote ; 
    done;
    for remote in `git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads/`; do
        echo Branch $remote;
        git checkout $remote;
        git pull;
    done
    git push -v --all upstream;
    cd ..;
done
```

In this solution, the script loops over all projects, and for each project, it does two other loops. In the first loop, the script identifies and start tracking all branches that are in the host (origin), even branches that are not tracked yet. In the second loop, the script makes pull of all branches. Finally, the script pushes all branches into new git host (upstream).

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to mirror a Git repo via intermediate repository (via CI / Jenkins) `--mirror` is not sufficient - because a CI repo is not a working repo, `refs/heads` are not populated!

You use refspec syntax:

```
git push https://evil.com/proj/repo +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Refs separated by colon denote `src:dst` - like every branch from `origin` to push to a remote mirror. Same for tags.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just compress a copy of the `.git` folder and send that off to another server?