# pushing to remote repo without removing history in remote

Tags: git

Yes I need to backup my local repo in remote repo and there are no collaborators.

I use `git push origin --mirror`

However there is slight problem( as I read it in [Is "git push --mirror" sufficient for backing up my repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333102/is-git-push-mirror-sufficient-for-backing-up-my-repository) ):
  It overwrites everything from local repo to remote. I guess if my local repo is corrupted, same will be transferred to the remote.

I don't want it. I want to push incremental changes as done in any incremental backup. The should be pushed on the top, preserving historical data.

What is the way to do it using git?

Comment: Create a branch?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
git push --all --tags -f
```

the -f will make it possible to remove stuff (if you've done a rebase). However things will be removed totally after 14 days and before that just being invisible