# How to maintain and refer a file, single copy for many git branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a situation: My `readme.md` file in `master` branch also needs to be on `gh-pages` branch.
If I make any changes to the file on one branch, I need to replicate them on other.

Is there a way to have common git branch that can be referred by other branches?
Or track a file in two branches simultaneously?

See https://github.com/anupam-arohi/lv for more details on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A branch is not "referred" by another, and a file with a new version in a branch will need to have said new version content "copied" somehow on the other branch.

You have two approaches:

1. once you change the file in one branch, you checkout the other branch and copy it (I mention a general script in "[How to update a file across all branches in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11946662/6309)")
   In your case, that would be

   ```
   git checkout gh-pages
   git checkout master -- aFile
   ```
2. Since the first option is not automatic, you could consider setting up a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) through a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309), a smudge script which, on checkout, would automatically copy the content of the file from the other branch.

   [image: smudge]
   <sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)")</sup>

That script would [get the content of the file from the other branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34146897/6309) and replace the content of that same file in the checked-out branch.

```
git show master:path/to/aFile > path/to/aFile
```