# How can I get number of commits on ALL branches per developer?

Tags: git, github

The following code does a great job but only on the current branch, how can I get the numbers for all the branches?

```
git pull  -v; git shortlog -s -n -e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
git shortlog -s -n -e --all
```

The `--all` makes it look as though all refs were put on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

What about using for-each-ref, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846380/how-to-iterate-through-all-git-branches-using-bash-script)

The command in your case would look like:

```
git for-each-ref --shell \
 --format='git shortlog -s -n -e ^origin/master %(refname)' \
 refs/heads/
```

You can then copy&paste the printed commands in the terminal which prints for each branch the shortlog (only the part after split from master I believe). Together with the command above (I assume you are in the master branch), you then have the full summary (and know who have been working on the different branches..).