# .gitignored some files only recently; trying to merge into a previous branch, ignored files show up as conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, gitignore

I had a branch `devel` from which I branched out `A` topic branch in the past.

`devel` was always intended to be the parent of `A` (everything `devel` had/hadn't should reflect in `A`). After a long time, I've added some files to `.gitignore` and [updated the index of `devel` to reflect it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/1266650)

Now I'm trying to merge `devel` back into `A` again.. to reflect those changes (`.gitignore`ed files from it) but it gives me a merge conflict in those ignored files. I don't want those ignored files in `A`. How do I tell that to git?

screenshot if it helps...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather, before merging `devel` to `A`, making sure all `devel` ignored files are ignored as well in `A`.

The trick for that is to remove from the index of `A` *everything*, update the `.gitignore` content, and add everything back!

```
git checkout A
# update the .gitignore file from devel in A
git checkout devel -- .gitignore

# remove/add everything
git rm --cached -r .
git add .
git commit -m "new commit with devel gitignore files out" 

# then
git merge devel
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I remove/add everything but with a GLOBAL gitignore? (so that it remove/add everything from ALL branches?)

Because otherwise it's basically just doing the same thing I did with the `devel` (remove/add everything acc. to new `.gitignore`). Merging after that would be kinda pointless...(except for preserving semantic-relationships) And I'll have to do this with every `A`,`B`,`C`…

Comment: @laggingreflex I would presume merging that would not be pointless: you would merge devel to all the branches, which can have non-ignored files with evolutions of their own, hence the merge. And you should be able to script my proposed sequence of commands easily enough for each branches (s i http://stackoverflow.com/a/3847586/6309).