# git branch vs $(git branch)

Tags: git, bash, subshell

When I execute `git branch` on the command line I get a list of all the branches on a repo, however when I execute `$(git branch)` in a sub-shell, it first prints out a list of files in the top level folder in a repo before printing out the branch names. Why?

I'm basically trying to iterate over the branches using a for loop, but the listing of files breaks my script.

```
for i in $(git branch); do 
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: I learned that this is the better solution to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846380/how-to-iterate-through-all-git-branches-using-bash-script

Answer (score 3):

```
$ git branch
* master
```

Try `echo * master` in your shell and see what you get?

Hint: You'll get the list of files in the current directory from the shell glob expansion of `*`.

See [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Because your first branch (or, the checked out branch) has a `*` next to it, which is a shell wild card. This is being evaluated and expanded to the list of files in the current directory.

Try checking out a branch further down the list, you'll find the list of files moves to be inserted in the list next to the currently checked out branch, *not* at the top.