# Get all git branches that matches regex and split it into array

Tags: regex, git, bash, git-branch

I'm trying to get from my git repo all branches (`git branches -a`) that matches regex (`grep xxx`).

Normally in command line I write this:

```
git branch -a | grep xxx
```

So I'm trying to do the same in .sh file:

1. get all branches that matches regex
2. split it into array
3. get first branch

Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

branches=( $(git branch -a | grep $1) )

echo branches : $branches
echo branch : ${branches[0]}
```

Sadly it somehow add all files in my current folder.

This is the output:

```
$> checkout.sh 2887
branches : ant 
branch : ant
```

If I change `branches=( $(git branch -a | grep $1) )` to `branches=$(git branch -a | grep $1)` I got all files in my dir and branches at the end

Comment: The "all files" thing is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812464/git-branch-vs-git-branch/24812543 .

Comment: @EtanReisner post is as an answer and you will get +

Comment: `git branch` takes patterns directly, no need for grep. `git branch -a --list "*$1*"` will do what you want there I believe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Etan has the simple approach in his comment.

You error may be happening because you fail to quote `$1`, so if you're passing a regular expression with wildcards (like `script 'release-.*'`), the shell will examine the variable before handing it off to `grep` -- word splitting and filename expansion will occur. You **must** quote variables whenever you don't absolutely control the contents.

Also, no reason to store the results in an array just to grab the first result, let `grep` handle that:

```
first_match=$( git branch -a | grep -m 1 "$1" )
```

But use `git branch -a --list pattern`