# git branch behaving odd in bash

Tags: git, bash

If I execute

```
 git version
 mkdir test
 cd test
 touch a b c
 git init
 git add -A
 git commit -m "test"
 git branch -a
 ls
 x=$(git branch -a); echo $x
```

I get the following output:

```
git version 2.4.2
* master
a  b  c
a b c master
```

First line is the git version.
Second is the `git branch -a`.
Third line is output of `ls`.
Fourth line is the output of `x=$(git branch -a); echo $x`

This is weird. Shouldn't lines 2 and 4 be equal?

Comment: Quote your use of `"$x"` and they will be. Unquoted the shell is expanding the `*` as a glob and listing all the files in the current directory.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24812464/258523 for another instance of this issue (and there are many more).

Comment: oh, how could I not see this. Thanks.
Please mark the question as duplicate or add you answer as "Answer".

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ (linked from the bash tag wiki) would have caught this one for you. :)

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I wasn't sure what to mark it a duplicate of exactly (which is a problem with a lot of the common shell issues). I sometimes wish I could mark things as duplicates of BasHFAQ entries or shellcheck warnings/wiki entries. =)