# for loop over all git branches with certain name

Tags: git

I have the following git branches

```
foo
bar
foobar
feature/foo
feature/bar
feature/buzz
```

How would you do a for loop over all branches that start with the word 'feature/' ?

When I try the following, it strangely prints out more than just the git branches.

```
for i in $(git branch --list "feature/*"); do echo $i; done;
stuff.txt
icon.jpg
morestuff.txt
Vagrantfile
feature/foo
feature/bar
feature/buzz
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through all git branches using bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846380/how-to-iterate-through-all-git-branches-using-bash-script)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"We actively discourage against use of any Porcelain command, including git branch, in scripts" - from the [Git Maintainer's Blog](http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2013/06/checking-current-branch-programatically.html)

You want to use something like

`git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/feature/`

which will work fine inside a `for br in $()` construct

Comment: I'll add that the reason `git branch` doesn't work is because the output includes a `*` next to the current branch. If you `echo *` or `for f in *; do echo $f; done` you get the contents of the current directory.