# Storing git branch -a in bash variable includes files

Tags: bash, git, variables, echo, git-branch

I run

```sh
.../$ git branch -a
  master
  temp
* version_1
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/temp
  remotes/origin/version_1
```

but then:

```
.../$ v="$(git branch -a)"
.../$ echo $v
master temp bent bent.sh core LICENSE notes old README.md res version_1 remotes/origin/master remotes/origin/temp remotes/origin/version_1
```

I get that storing a variable this way removes the new lines (& need to look up how to fix that).

But why, oh why, is it adding my files (`bent bent.sh core LICENSE notes old README.md res`) and how can I stop it?

I'm trying to get an array of branch names, so I can make a prompt to choose branch name via a number

Comment: Same thing happens with `git branch -l`, but not `git branch -r`

Comment: the newlines are there. Add quotes in the `echo` command. The files are from the `*` which is expanded in the echo command.

Comment: Ohhhh! Because it's executing `echo *` on that line, basically? Makes sense. That did it! I think I've known that before... lol

Comment: Other useful links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846380/how-to-iterate-through-all-git-branches-using-bash-script and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724818/for-loop-over-all-git-branches-with-certain-name