# git scripting: How to list all git branches containing a commit

Tags: git, bash, git-plumbing

I can list [all branches containing a certain commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit) using `git branch --list --contains` just fine. But as explained in the related [question on how to list all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846380/how-to-iterate-through-all-git-branches-using-bash-script), this is a porcelain command that should not be used in scripts.

The latter question suggests to use the plumbing command `git for-each-ref`, but that does not support `--contains`.

What is the correct plumbing interface to list all branches that contain a certain commit.

Comment: Note: with git 2.7 (Q4 2015), `git for-each-ref --contains` will be a reality. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32988289/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution using the plumbing commands `git-for-each-ref` and `git merge-base` (the latter suggested by Joachim himself):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# git-branchesthatcontain.sh
#
# List the local branches that contain a specific revision
#
# Usage: git branchthatcontain <rev>
#
# To make a Git alias called 'branchesthatcontain' out of this script,
# put the latter on your search path, and run
#
#   git config --global alias.branchesthatcontain \
#       '!sh git-branchesthatcontain.sh'

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    printf "%s\n\n" "usage: git branchesthatcontain <rev>"
    exit 1
fi

rev=$1

git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | \
    while read ref; do
        if git merge-base --is-ancestor "$rev" "$ref"; then
            printf "%s\n" "$ref"
        fi;
    done

exit $?
```

The script is available at [Jubobs/git-aliases](https://github.com/Jubobs/git-aliases) on GitHub.

(Edit: thanks to [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124319/coredump) for showing me [how to get rid of that nasty `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938034/2541573).)

Comment: looks similar to what I ended up doing, but I used `git merge-base --is-ancestor` instead of `[ -n "$(git rev-list $rev^..$ref)" ]`.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Good call, using `git merge-base --is-ancestor`. Less hacky, more robust. I didn't even know about it (thanks!). Post your own answer, or let me know if I should just edit mine.

Comment: Mine is not using fancy `eval` stuff (personal distrust), so do update yours if you think it is an improvement.

Comment: Any reason to use the `eval` variable, and not just `eval "$(git for-each-ref ... )"`?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner No good reasons, no. The `eval` variable is a holdover from the example in the [`git-for-each-ref` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref).

Answer (score 5):

**Update 18 months later (April 2017)**: with Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), `git for-each-ref --no-contains <SHA1>` is finally supported!

See [commit 7505769](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75057691beb804e804df21992ae55d50ffc36f92), [commit 783b829](https://github.com/git/git/commit/783b829287952ec42bf89d9ca42fc6c51d7d0143), [commit ac3f5a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac3f5a346860b824e083c5d305757c3260565475), [commit 1e0c3b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e0c3b680c6e7b37fc51bd69a410af01897a4f94), [commit 6a33814](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a338149f623f493525324bc0f8d7bb9257cb840), [commit c485b24](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c485b24c427254fe36c2c6cc970519b797abd6bc), [commit eab98ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eab98ee5ab84def96012f115a8e10571c6e24e4e), [commit bf74804](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf748049f53cea3662b02d87cc91d44a0164e588) (24 Mar 2017), [commit 7ac04f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ac04f1398c4e854cb585bd289ee4fe921984bbd), [commit 682b29f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/682b29f90d7e049c24f3821d49599dceb4aeb758), [commit 4612edc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4612edc639e8c7c15420960a92efa609e92ab9a7), [commit b643827](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b643827b9443deadaa5804998116107953f8b42f) (23 Mar 2017), and [commit 17d6c74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17d6c744dc0d5ed4cd0f228da14239ea2654f05b), [commit 8881d35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8881d35cace41604dba72c1b6b5ab5a59e0c2b94), [commit b084060](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b084060921d6403164e8dee506de787d017569c3), [commit 0488792](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0488792d2e56bfe38be6ea7f5456bd3286c807b8) (21 Mar 2017) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d1d3d46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1d3d46146e1256efe8ad2a2bb0dd877a738c07d), 11 Apr 2017)</sup>

---

**Original answer**

Starting git 2.7 (Q4 2015) you will get a more complete version of [`git for-each-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), which now support the `--contains`

```
git for-each-ref --contains <SHA1>
```

With the doc:

```
--contains [<object>]:
```

> Only list tags which contain the specified commit (HEAD if not specified).

---

See [commit 4a71109](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a71109aa442ba1a7045d36f6b148113c95ffc48), [commit ee2bd06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee2bd06b0f735a00ce0216ca1d3391b13722d987), [commit f266c91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f266c9163b34ec55e453d27e1ed246d67ee3ced0), [commit 9d306b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d306b5a6077f026291df3c4a5968eaf95a92417), [commit 7c32834](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c32834813bd6aee5ce5b2c4131d9f34249bc9e3), [commit 35257aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35257aa01203bae74f9fb856fb02c10c4b3836e6), [commit 5afcb90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5afcb90560586765bf21fb09959a8b4497804639), ..., [commit b2172fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2172fdf702426cb4eba093b5504d0a0e9e59746) (07 Jul 2015), and [commit af83baf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af83bafa4867ba16368e58f36e8311e9591e68f4) (09 Jul 2015) by [Karthik Nayak (`KarthikNayak`)](https://github.com/KarthikNayak).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9958dd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9958dd8685a0a8b3d6ecdd07e35d8ecb22b304a7), 05 Oct 2015)</sup>

> Some features from "`git tag -l`" and "`git branch -l`" have been made
>   available to "`git for-each-ref`" so that eventually the unified
>   implementation can be shared across all three, in a follow-up
>   series or two.

```
* kn/for-each-tag-branch:
  for-each-ref: add '--contains' option
  ref-filter: implement '--contains' option
  parse-options.h: add macros for '--contains' option
  parse-option: rename parse_opt_with_commit()
  for-each-ref: add '--merged' and '--no-merged' options
  ref-filter: implement '--merged' and '--no-merged' options
  ref-filter: add parse_opt_merge_filter()
  for-each-ref: add '--points-at' option
  ref-filter: implement '--points-at' option
```