# How can I avoid using 'eval' in conjunction with 'git-for-each-ref'?

Tags: git, shell, security, eval

Most advanced uses of `git for-each-ref` that I've come across involve `eval`. For instance, [the last example in the `git-for-each-ref` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_examples) uses `eval` in order to execute the contents of the `fmt` variable:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

fmt='
    r=%(refname)
    # ... omitted, for conciseness ...
    '

eval=`git for-each-ref --shell --format="$fmt" \
    # ... omitted, for conciseness ...
    refs/tags`
eval "$eval"
```

However, [the use of `eval` is associated with security risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead); avoiding it, whenever possible, is considered good practice.

Here is a real example, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854997/2541573):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

fmt='
    ref=%(refname:short)

    if git merge-base --is-ancestor $1 $ref; then
      printf "%s\n" "$ref"
    fi
'

eval "$(git for-each-ref --shell --format="$fmt" refs/heads/)"
```

In this particular example, how can I avoid using `eval`? I've reviewed the options listed in [Zenexer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529221/2541573), but I couldn't find one that does the trick. I'm looking for as portable (across different shells) a solution as possible.

Comment: IMHO it is hackish to do so, even if the man page suggests that. You'll find better ways than eval. You might for example create a json,xml,csv (or whatever) file with `git for-each-ref` and use it as input for a shell script or shell function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of treating data as code using `eval`, you let `git for-each-ref` output a stream of data in a format that is easy for you to process. Then, you write a custom processor for that data.

```
git for-each-ref --format "<values>" \
     # more options
     refs/tags | while read refname object_type <more args> ; do
          <code>
     done
```

As for the specific example you gave, here is an equivalent non-eval version:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    printf "usage: git branchesthatcontain <rev>\n\n"
    exit 1
fi

rev=$1

git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads \
    | while read ref; do 
          if git merge-base --is-ancestor "$rev" "$ref"; then
              echo "$ref"
          fi;
      done

exit $?
```

I must add that `git-for-each-ref` does include `--shell`, `--python` and `--tcl` flags which ensures that the data is properly escaped: this is not the same scenario as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529221/124319) to the question you reference.

[This question and the associated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil?rq=1) are also relevant.

Comment: For completeness, I would also like to see the method applied to an actual example. I'll edit my question and add one there.

Comment: @Jubobs Here it is. I removed the part about nul-delimited strings because I don't see a way to actually prevent the command from outputting newlines, even though %00 would output the NUL character. But this is not needed either since `for-each-ref` can quote the output.

Comment: Great stuff. I like the stream approach, which seems much more functional in spirit. Can I update [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31854997/2541573), if I properly acknowledge [yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31938034/2541573)?

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks; and yes, of course, you can update your answer (I did not notice it was yours ;-) )

Comment: Thanks. 200 pts of rep' well spent `:)`