# Find tags in which a commit appears

Tags: git

I have a git commit hash and I'm interested in finding which tags contain this commit. This seems like it should be easy, but I've been unable to find any solution.  How can I achieve this with git?

Comment: Or `git tag --contains`

Comment: Would you need to list such commits in a script or not? If not, Andrew's suggestion will do fine. Otherwise, you should eschew Git porcelain commands. One way is to use a modified version of this [script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853701/git-scripting-how-to-list-all-git-branches-containing-a-commit/31854997#31854997) (replace `refs/heads` by `refs/tags`).

Comment: @AndrewC - looks like a great answer, why not create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sitting at your terminal and wish to know then

`git tag --contains`

If you are trying to get this information for a script and

-- you are using an older version of Git (<= 2.5) then you will need to script around `git for-each-ref` and `git merge-base --is-ancestor` as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853701/git-scripting-how-to-list-all-git-branches-containing-a-commit/31854997#31854997).

-- you are using a newer versions of Git (>=2.6)  then you would use `git for-each-ref --contains`.  This is both simpler and has better performance.