# How to find commit by SHA of a submodule?

Tags: git

I have a repo which has a submodule. For a given SHA of the submodule, I want to find commits in the repo where this submodule exists and has the given SHA.

How would I do this with the most recent version of git?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) to read that **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309)) to read the SHA1 of a submodule:

```
git ls-tree HEAD mysubmodule 
160000 commit c0f065504bb0e8cfa2b107e975bb9dc5a34b0398  mysubmodule
```

That will include the SHA1 at which the submodule is recorded in the parent repo.

Knowing that, you can combine it with a [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), using an index filter (to avoid having to checkout the parent repo for each commit)

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git ls-tree mysubmodule' -- --all|grep <yourSHA1>
```

A shell approach combining [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) and [`git ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) is probably cleaner:

```
#!/bin/sh
for r in $(git rev-list FIRST_REV..LAST_REV) 
do 
    git ls-tree $r mysubmodule
done | grep <yourSHA1>
```

With [git 2.7, you will soon get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32988289/6309):

```
git for-each-ref --contains <SHA1>
```

That should be easier.

Comment: That's not what I asked for. I want for a given SHA of a submodule to find commits in the repo that has it.

Comment: @Kentzo so find in the parent repo commits the commits which reference a gitlink specific SHA1?

Comment: @Kentzo OK. I'll have to test it, but the first approach would be to use a filter-branch. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hm, this strikes me off-hand as abuse of filter-branch, although it should work fine (it just "feels wrong" to use a rewrite tool when you're not rewriting—and the `--prune-empty` might actually make changes, too).  There's no other command that will quickly scan through each commit though.  Perhaps git needs a `for-each-object` command, a la `for-each-ref`...

Comment: @torek I agree. I am still experimenting as we speak (write)

Comment: @torek note that for-each-ref is soon greatly improved with git 2.7 (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6309+for-each-ref+2.7)

Comment: I fail to see how `for-each-ref` solves this problem. Using the given command in this answer, it doesn't work in the parent repo because the SHA1 specified doesn't exist in the parent, it is a commit in the submodule. And `for-each-ref` doesn't inspect file contents to match SHA1s using the gitlink.

Comment: @void.pointer "because the SHA1 specified doesn't exist in the parent" Yes it should (exist in the parent): we are talking about the gitlink SHA1, that is the SHA1 of the root tree of the submodule repo, as recorded by the parent repo.

Comment: @VonC But for all intents and purposes, that's file contents, not an actual SHA1 in the parent repo itself. Point is, I ran your command and it failed. I do not see an example of how `for-each-ref` helps you find the SHA1 of the parent repo that contains a modification to point to a different SHA1 of a submodule. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, I do not see how this solves the problem. Need a better example/explanation.

Comment: @void.pointer "that's file contents": that is not how I interpreted the OP's request at the time (3+ years ago). For me, "has the given SHA" refers to the root tree of the submodule repo, not to a file content.

Comment: @void.pointer But don't hesitate to illustrate your issue in a separate question, with an example, what you got vs. what you expected.