# AWS CodeCommit Submodule Blob doesn't Exist

Tags: git, git-submodules, aws-codecommit

I have a CodeCommit repo with a submodule. The submodule is another repo within CodeCommit.

When I attempt to view what is in the submodule from within the parent repo, I get an error that says:

`AWS CodeCommit could not find the blob`

Any idea on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means the first CodeCommit repo is referencing a SHA1 for the second repo tree, ... which has not been pushed by the second repo to CodeCommit.

You can see that SHA1 (in a local clone of the first repo) [with `git ls-tree master <path-to-directory-containing-submodule>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033973/6309).
See "[How to find commit by SHA of a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34543003/6309)".

You need to make sure the second repo (the one acting as submodule for the first repo) has pushed that SHA1.