# Git rm "No such file or directory"

Tags: git

I'm trying to run the git rm command but it returns with:

`No such file or directory`

I tried executing the following commands from the project root directory but none worked:

```
git rm --cached Videos/video-1.mp4
git rm --cached /Videos/video-1.mp4
git rm --cached ./Videos/video-1.mp4
git rm --cached ~/Videos/video-1.mp4
```

The file does in fact exist in this folder. I'm using a MacBook.

Comment: Your attempts suggest you have an incomplete grasp of how the file system works, and so it's hard to assess your statement that the file actually exists. Please [edit] to provide details about what exactly exists and where exactly. Where is the `.git` folder relative to where you are running these commands? Perhaps see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and/55342466)

Comment: perhaps a FS casing problem sticking out its head?

Comment: If `git rm --cached` cannot find some file, it says `fatal: pathspec '...' did not match any files`, so `git rm` is not running in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> The file does in fact exist in this folder

Yes, but check if Videos itself is not the root folder of a submodule repository (check for a `.gitmodules` in your project root directory).
Or check the [output of `git ls-tree master Videos`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34543003/6309)

If you see `160000`, that means Videos is a nested Git repository, and you cannot `git rm` a file from the parent repository.

Note that generally `$HOME` (`~`) is rarely a Git repository, and large binary files like video files are rarely added to a *source* control system like Git.

Comment: No submodule repositories exist. It's just one repo.

Comment: @Johann Syill, what does `git ls-tree master Videos` return? (when executed in its parent folder)

Comment: "No such file or directory"

Comment: What does `git version` return? What does `which git` return? What does `file $(which git)` return? (My suspicion is that there is something wrong with your `git` command in general, not with `git rm` in particular).

Comment: @Johann Did you see J6t's comment?

Comment: @Johann : does `git ls-tree master videos` (with lowercase `v`) also say "No such file or directory" ?