# How to filter branch name with keyword?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash

I am using this logic and need the only branch name that match this string "AMAZONFIX".

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate:short) %(authordate:relative) %(refname:lstrip=3)' --sort -committerdate refs/remotes/$REMOTE_NAME | while read date branch; do
printf "%s | %s %s %s %s %s | %50s\n" $date $branch
```

Output result :

```
feature/core-xyz
dummy/AMAZON-bitMap
bugfix/AMAZONFIX-work
main/outlet-file
```

Excepted Output :

```
dummy/AMAZONFIX-bitMap
bugfix/work-place-AMAZONFIX
```

Only the branch name that having "AMAZONFIX"

Comment: Pipe it through grep for AMAZONFIX?

Answer (score 0):

If you do nnot want to use a post-processing step like `| grep AMAZONFIX`, consider the [`git for-each-ref --contains=...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---containsltobjectgt) directive (introduced with [Git 2.7, Q4 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32988289/6309))

In your case, on multiple lines, for readability:

```
git for-each-ref \
  --format='%(committerdate:short) %(authordate:relative) 
            %(refname:lstrip=3)' 
  --contains=$REMOTE_NAME/AMAZONFIX --contains=AMAZONFIX 
  --sort -committerdate refs/remotes/origin | \
  while read date branch; \
    do printf "%s | %s %s %s %s %s | %50s\n" $date $branch; 
  done
```

However, that would only work for branches named `AMAZONFIX`, not `xxxAMAZONFIXyyy`

Since `--contains` does not support wildcard, `grep` remains the best option:

```
git for-each-ref...| while... ;done | grep AMAZONFIX
```

Comment: I tried same but getting Error as : error: malformed object name origin/AMAZONFIX   @VonC

Comment: @rowoc Indeed: it works on my side, but only because I have a branch named `AMAZONFIX`. In your case, a grep remains the best option. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks it worked @VonC