# Git list of remote branches

Tags: git, powershell, foreach, git-branch

I'm looking for the best way to execute a function for each Git remote branch in a PowerShell script.

I don't know the best way to get a list of Git remote branches. I can successfully list all remote branches, but I always end up with pesky formatting in the branch names.

Here are the commands I've tried and the resulting arrays I've gotten.

```
$allBranches = git branch -r
$allBranches = @('  origin/branch1', '  origin/branch2', '  origin/branch3')

$allBranches = git for-each-ref --shell --format=%(refname) refs/remotes/origin
$allBranches = @(''origin/branch1'', ''origin/branch2'', ''origin/branch3'')
```

I would like
`$allBranches = @('origin/branch1', 'origin/branch2', 'origin/branch3')`, so my current approach is to just manually remove formatting from the weird branch names using `Trim()`:

```
foreach($branch in $allBranches) {
    # Format $branch
    # Do function
}
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846380/how-to-iterate-through-all-git-branches-using-bash-script has Bash in the title but really contains the Git magic you want

Comment: Are you looking for Powershell code to format the returned branch names easily, or a better git call that doesn't include the extra spaces?

Comment: I am looking for a Powershell script, not a Bash script. I know how to format the branch names. I would like a better git call or a better way to iterate through the branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trim() operation should do what you want.

```
$allTrimmedBranches = @()
foreach($branch in $allBranches) {
    $allTrimmedBranches += $branch.Trim()
}
#do function
```

Comment: My current approach is to trim the branch names, which seems rather inefficient. I would like a better git call or a better way to iterate through the branches.

Comment: How many branches do you have? The time/resources it takes to trim a hundred or fewer strings are negligible.

Comment: I have <100 branches. However, I'm wondering if there's a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
$branches = git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes/origin
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and/or description to your answer.