# why git branch and $(git branch) outputs different result

Tags: git, bash, shell, unix, version-control

I'm trying to make a bash script which will print commits ahead of current branch in other branches. However, when I execute command `git branch` in a subshell, I get not only branch names but also list of files and folders in the current directory. Why calling `$(git branch)` behaves this way?

Comment: maybe in a different directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the command substitution, it's the quoting. Here is the result of `git branch` on a repo:

```
$ git branch
  5-job-test-fails
* master
  revisions
  with_cool_background
```

Notice the askerisk.

When you write `echo $(git branch)`, since the argument is unquoted, the asterisk will expand to the files in the current directory:

```
$ echo $(git branch)
5-job-test-fails app bin cable config config.ru db erd.pdf Gemfile Gemfile.lock Guardfile lib log public Rakefile README.rdoc test tmp vendor master revisions with_cool_background
```

To overcome this, quote the argument:

```
$ echo "$(git branch)"
  5-job-test-fails
* master
  revisions
  with_cool_background
```

Comment: Wow, never thought this would be the case. How about if I must build foreach statement which iterates over all the branches? How to deal with the star?

Comment: You have to remove the star anyway before processing the branch name. There are a few alternatives on how to do it in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846380/how-to-iterate-through-all-git-branches-using-bash-script. It's probably best not to use `git branch` at all in scripts according to the accepted answer there.