# List all local git branches without an asterisk

Tags: git, git-branch

If I run `git branch`, I get something like:

```
* master
  dev
  foo
```

if I do `git branch -r`, it will show all branches on the remote, without an asterisk (where the asterisk shows my current checked-out branch).

How can I list all the local branches, without an asterisk showing up? I need a programmatic solution so I can read in the results line-by-line.

Comment: You can just trim the leading whitespaces and remove the asterisk by using regular expressions. I'm sure the programming language you are using makes this possible.

Comment: @tangoal: you *can* do this, but that's almost certainly not the best way. The Git authors divide their commands loosely into what they call *plumbing* and *porcelain*. A plumbing command is meant for other commands to use, while a porcelain command is meant for humans to use. Hence the output of a plumbing command is typically best-suited as input to another program, rather than for eyeballing. `git for-each-ref` is the plumbing command that implements `git branch --list`, `git tag --list`, and several others.

Comment: That's way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72170904/990047

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [`for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref):

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/
```

Comment: you can pass `:short` or `lstrip=-1` to refname to get only the branch name. Like `git branch --format='%(refname:short)'`

Comment: @JohnnyWiller's suggestion of `git branch --format` also works with branch names that contain slashes, which the answer doesn't.

Comment: @Milles use more wildcards for heads. e.g.; `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/dev/* refs/heads/*`

Comment: A quick and dirty solution `git branch | cut -c 3-`, who doesn't like a quick and dirty solution?

Comment: Use `refs/heads/**` to include branch names with slashes.

Comment: @JoeyAdams Just omitting any `*`s works for me too: `refs/heads`

Comment: This does not preserve the configured sort order, while @JohnnyWiller's suggestion does