# Why is git branch showing me files when run in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, git

If I run `git branch` in a terminal, I get this output:

```
  abstract-controller
  core-button-bar
* dev
  final-core-datatable
  generic-loan-search-exp
  working-tags
```

I have a Bash script that looks like this:

```
branches=$(git branch)
echo ${branches)
```

It does output the branches, but also includes all of the files in the current directory.

```
abstract-controller core-button-bar README.md config <<all the other files>> dev final-core-datatable generic-loan-search-exp working-tags
```

First, why is it doing this, and second, how can I get *just* the branches?

Comment: May be this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846380/how-to-iterate-through-all-git-branches-using-bash-script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git branch` is not doing it.  Your *shell* is doing it:

1. What does `echo *` print, in your shell?
2. Who expanded `*`?

Once you know and understand the answers to these, you know what happened with `git branch`.

Git, being sensibly written,<sup>1</sup> has its commands neatly—or sometimes messily—divided into programs whose output is *designed* for *other programs* to consume, and programs whose output is *designed* for *humans* to read.  The former programs are called *plumbing* and the latter are called *porcelain*.

The plumbing version of `git branch` is `git for-each-ref`, run with `refs/heads/` as a limiting *refspec*.  The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) tells you what `--format` directives to use here as well.  You probably want just `%(refname:short)`.

---

<sup>1</sup>For some values of sensibly anyway.