# Is there a way to create different webpages with each branch in one repo using GitLab/gh-pages?

Tags: github, gitlab, github-pages

I'd like to figure out if it's possible to create different web pages per each branch using one repo either using GitLab or gh-pages. At this point, I am willing to switch between both since this is something I'd really like to do. I have found solutions that are reliant on cache, which I would hope to move away from. I have been stumped on this for a while and have tried multiple solutions on GitLab, but have yet to try anything via gh-pages.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Only one site is supported on these platforms. You cannot have separate sites for separate branches.

The only way you might do this without some sort of cache/artifact retrieval (as you mentioned is another option in your question) is to build all your branches at once when publishing your Pages site.

How *exactly* you do that depends on a lot of factors, including what tool(s) you're using to build your site and if they are context-dependent -- but it might look something like this in GitLab

```yaml
pages:
  # fetch the whole repo
  # this logic can change if you're on a detached head, like an MR
  # so we account for that here
  before_script: | 
        if [[ -n "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" ]]; then  # branch pipelines
            git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git"
            git fetch origin
            git checkout $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
        fi
        if [[ -n "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID" ]]; then  # MR pipelines
            git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_PROJECT_PATH}.git"
            git fetch origin
        fi
  script: |
        mkdir public
        branches=()
        # ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3847586/5747944
        eval "$(git for-each-ref --shell --format='branches+=(%(refname))' refs/heads/)"
        for branch in "${branches[@]}"; do
            git checkout "$branch"
            # build each branch and output to public directory
            # YOU implement this
            make build "$branch" -o "public/${branch}"
        done
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  environment: # ensure outdated jobs are skipped
    name: pages # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/deployment_safety.html#skip-outdated-deployment-jobs
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `${$CI_JOB_TOKEN}`