# Git migrate repo to another server

Tags: git

I realize that this question has been asked several times. I went through almost all of those before asking it here.

I have a git repo on server A and want it to push on remote server B.

Steps i followed:

On server B:

```
    mkdir repo
    cd repo
    git init --bare
    ls
    branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

On server A where my local repo is present.

```
cd localrepo
git remote add new-origin root@B:/root/repo
git push new-origin master
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 976 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To root@172.16.189.221:/root/four
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Now when i check on server B. Cannot find the updated files. 
each time i update on localrepo on A and do a push to B. it updates the contents under objects folder in B but am unable to see the files.

Could anyone point me in the right direction :)

Comment: I'm not too versed in Git, but shouldn't server B be adding the remote and cloning/pulling from server A?

Comment: Well i forgot to mention that the pulling worked fine.
I was referring to various websites which mention a push.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/moving-git-repository-new-server/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484648/how-to-migrate-git-repository-from-one-server-to-a-new-one

Just curious to know if i am doing it wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

A bare repository does not contain a working tree. (That's why it is called bare.) Therefore you cannot see the files directly. (You see only those files, which live in `.git` on a non-bare repository.)

Use `git ls-files` to see which files are present. Use `git log` to see which commits are present.

To actually "move" the repository to another server I would simply use

```
git clone --mirror $original_url
```

on the new server.