# Migrate repositories from one server(Virtual machine) to another server(local machine)

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

I want to migrate GITHUB server having 100’s of repositories on Virtual machine and to migrate it on a physical machine.Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484648/how-to-migrate-git-repository-from-one-server-to-a-new-one

Comment: Migrating from a VM to a (real) server should not, in theory, be any different than migrating from one real server to another real server.

Comment: You should just ask GitHub support

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In the stack question you have mentioned,he's moving only one repo,my job is to move all repositories on a server to a local machine

Comment: GitHub Enterprise is delivered as a virtual appliance and will require a hypervisor.  Is this a question about migrating to another machine hosting GitHub Enterprise or migrating to a vanilla Git server on a physical machine?