# In Git, my origin was lost, how do I convert a working copy to a new origin?

Tags: git, copy, mirror

I have a development host pats1 that has a GIT repo in a directory on the host:

```
~pats/gitrepos/myrepo.git
```

The repo holds some personal scripts and development tools that I clone to other boxes (say host1 and host2) when I'm doing development on the other hosts.  I just use ssh to clone and push updates;  There is no github or "real server" being used.

My pats1 box died (hard disk VM was wiped out), and I'm wondering what steps to take to get a new replacement repo set up by using data from the existing copies.

**I want to know what steps to take to convert one of the working git copies of myrepo on host1 or host2 and setup a pats2:gitrepos/myrepo.git to be the new central server and point the existing working repos (on host1 and host2) to the new server.**

Questions similar to this have been asked.  Some are:

[How to migrate GIT repository from one server to a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484648/how-to-migrate-git-repository-from-one-server-to-a-new-one)

[Convert a normal repo to a bare one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-normal-git-repository-to-a-bare-one)

Some of the answers given require the old server to be around which is not an option for me.  Below are the steps I think I need to follow:

**(1) Pick one of the hosts to create the new "central server (pats2)".**  *Is one host better to use than the other?*

For this example, I'll pick **host1**.

**(2) Make sure the repo on host1 contains everything you want copied.**

This post [Atlassian Developer Tip of Week - Copying a full git repo](https://legacy-developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/01/totw-copying-a-full-git-repo/) says to **do this the right way** I would want to make sure the local repo has all of the branches of the remote/origin checked out so that when the repo is cloned, the branches are present.

Well, since my origin host (pats1) is not available, I might have some references to remote branches that are not checked out in the local repo.
*I believe this will automatically be cleaned up when I copy using git clone --mirror based on something I read but can't find the link to the article.*

So for this step, I'm stuck with what I have in the repo on host1 which in my case is fine because I only have a master branch. :-)

This article [how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/) says I should delete non-existent references as well using:

```
git fetch --prune
```

NOTE: This failed when I tried it because it couldn't access the origin.

**(3) Create a mirror of the repo on host1.**

```
ssh host1; cd proj
git clone --mirror myrepo myrepo.git
```

I'm using --mirror because [How to properly mirror a git repository](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/) says :

> Also git clone --mirror is prefered over git clone --bare because the former also clones git notes and some other attributes.

**(4) Copy that repo.git (repo) to my new server (pats2):**

```
ssh pats2 mkdir gitrepos
scp -r myrepo.git pats2:gitrepos/
```

The above command puts it in the correct place (~pats/gitrepos/myrepo.git) so in the future I can clone it using the command

```
git clone pats2:gitrepos/myrepo
```

NOTE: If the repo were large I might want to tar with compression and untar to minimize network bandwith, for example [tar czf - myrepo.git | mbuffer -s 1K -m 512 | ssh otherhost "cd gitrepos; tar zxf -"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48399/fast-way-to-copy-a-large-file-on-a-lan)

**(5) Point the existing hosts that have working copies of myrepo to point to the new repo location (on pats2)**

```
ssh host1; cd proj/myrepo; 
git remote set-url origin pats2:gitrepos/myrepo.git

Repeat above command for all hosts that were using the old "central1" host (pats1).
```

I hope someone else finds this useful and others can confirm that what I'm planning to do will work.

Comment: "origin" is just the default name of a *remote*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps seem good.

On 5, you can simply do:

```
cd proj/myrepo
git remote set-url origin pats2:gitrepos/myrepo.git
```

That will change the URL associated with `origin`.

Comment: Thanks @VonC for the improvement.  I've updated my question to reflect this, and selected this as the answer.