# How to import a project from the codeplex archive into github?

Tags: c#, github, codeplex

To my surprise, there is little to no usable information on the topic. Even the page on GitHub "[Importing a repository with GitHub Importer](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer/)", although explicitly mentioning [Codeplex](https://aka.ms/codeplex-guide), refers to an archived item.

My goal is simple:

**I want the source code of my [archived C# project](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=replayer), as is, have transferred into a public GitHub repository of mine.**

I don't worry about commits, issues, or any history. How to do that in a simple way? Preferrably not involving any download/local processing.

Comment: I have doubts it is even possible without any local processing. But this is trivial to do with the Git command line. See [How to migrate GIT repository from one server to a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484648/how-to-migrate-git-repository-from-one-server-to-a-new-one).

Comment: @NightOwl888 This seems to miss the point. I have a subversion repository that once was with codeplex, not a GIT one.

Comment: Nowhere in your question is the word "subversion". But [converting from subversion to Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-do-i-migrate-an-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository), is also possible from the command line (just not as trivial). There is plenty of information about this topic, as long as you understand that "Github" and "Codeplex" have nothing to do with the problem at hand, as they are simply hosting the repository on their server.

Comment: @NightOwl888 You are right about subversion. It was just the way me (and probably many) accessed the Codeplex repo. I just hoped that there is someone out there that already transferred their repo to Github and had a step-by-step tutorial at hand.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that Microsoft didn't make a tool to make the migration simpler, but the command line is always there to fall back on. BTW - I did find a couple of step by step tutorials [Migrating a Project from CodePlex to GitHub](https://vfpx.github.io/migrating/index.html) and [Migrating from SVN to GitHub](http://www.ganshani.com/blog/2014/12/migrating-from-svn-to-github/).