# Can I some how migrate my repo with all commits history from BitBucket to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Is it possible change endpoint in .git files from Bit Bucket to GitHub and make commit also to GitHub with all commits history?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate GIT repository from one server to a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484648/how-to-migrate-git-repository-from-one-server-to-a-new-one)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+migrate+history

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change your local repositorys' remote. From [this article](https://befused.com/git/github-bitbucket-move), describing how to move from GitHub to BitBucket:

> Change the origin URL
>
> 1. Go to the repository on your local machine on the command line
> 2. Type: git remote -v. This should show that the repo origin is still on github. E.g.
>
>    ```
>    origin https://USERNAME@github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME.git (fetch)
>    origin https://USERNAME@github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME.git (push)
>    ```
> 3. Edit the git config file for the repository: sudo nano .git/config
> 4. Change url (under remote "origin") and change github.com to bitbucket.com. You may need to change the username if your username is
>      different on bitbucket. You should also change it to the git URL. i.e.
>      git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPONAME.git

You just have to switch GitHub and BitBucket. Be sure to be up to date in your local repository (i.e. `git pull` before).

The GitHub repository should be a newly created, empty repository. Performing `git push` will move all your code with commit history to the new repo.

Comment: You should also make sure that anybody else working on that repo updates their stuff.