# Is it possible for me to import a bitbucket repo to gitlab using GitPython?

Tags: python, git, gitlab, bitbucket, gitpython

I currently have a bitbucket repo and am trying to import it to Gitlab using GitPython and I'm stuck as to how to do this. Is it possible and if so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: The question is why GitPython? Is there a special use case for that?

Comment: @RenéHöhle not really I thought using GitPython might be the easiest way to do this. Do you think I should use the GitLab API instead?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the regular command line Git: clone from bitbucket, and push to a fresh empty repo in GitLab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484648/how-to-migrate-git-repository-from-one-server-to-a-new-one