# Moving repository from one isolated network to another

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a Git repository on a internal private network that I would like to move to another internal private network.  The two networks are not connected to each other.  I created a mirror of the source repository using:

```
git clone --mirror <URL to my OLD repo location>
```

I transferred the cloned files to the destination network and they are stored in the ~/project.git directory.  On the destination network I have a new repository which is only populated with a README file.

I saw  [one similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484648/how-to-migrate-git-repository-from-one-server-to-a-new-one) which recommended this:

```
git remote set-url origin <URL to my NEW repo location>
git push -f origin
```

However, the push -f option is blocked per IT policy.  I've tried cloning the new repo and running this:

```
git pull ~/project.git master
```

But that have me an error due to the unrelated histories and didn't copy the history over.  How can I merge the contents of a mirrored Git repo (all of the history for multiple branches) into a new repo?  Thanks!

Comment: Just clone it, ignoring that other new repository with a readme file. `git clone ~/project.git <URL to NEW repo location>`. Or is "NEW location" not in the same filesystem as `~/project.git`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The two networks are not connected to each other.

Then [use a `git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309): you can copy one file, then pull from it in a new empty local repository on your second network.