# Can we copy windows file system for migrating Git server

Tags: git

I see a lot of literature on Git server migration @ [How to migrate GIT repository from one server to a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484648/how-to-migrate-git-repository-from-one-server-to-a-new-one) but isn't the easiest option to just copy over the file system to a new server

I assume nothing would break except for the git clients where they would have to change the .git/config remote url which isn't an issue in my case since the end url is the same. It is just the back-end server that has changed.

Are there any other issue with doing a file system copy for Git for Windows migration ?

Comment: Try and and let us know?

Comment: It should be fine. Just be sure the access to the repository is taken down for the duration of the transfer (technically, it should be fine to allow fetches).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you want to avoid in that scenario is somebody doing changes on the source URLs before finishing the copy. Make the share is read-only before starting the copy.

Comment: Thanks, hoping to make the source read only. Still working on getting it up

Comment: If you like you can update the original question with details to help you with. (Specific facing issues for example)